# Do Sebaceans feel cold to John Crichton?

Tags: farscape

In “Exodus From Genesis” (Farscape season 1, episode 3), we learn that Aeryn Sun and other Sebaceans are [cold-blooded](https://www.tor.com/2012/02/29/farscape-rewatch-exodus-from-genesis/). Or at least they have a tolerance for temperature that is lower on the scale than that of humans. In either case, Aeryn's touch should feel icy on John Crichton's skin. Does Crichton ever mention, in a context when she is feeling well, that Aeryn (or any other Sebacean) feels cold to him?

Comment: Low tolerance to heat doesn't imply cold-bloodedness.

Comment: ***D'Argo:** Sebaceans lack the gland necessary to regulate extreme thermal increases. **John:** Wait - Crais and those other bastards chasing us are cold-blooded? Literally?* - It's not confirmed that they're cold-blooded

Comment: True. Also, human skin is usually maintained at a lower temperature than the body's core temperature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the the Farscape Extended Universe novel [*Farscape: The Dark Side of the Sun*](https://farscape.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Side_of_the_Sun), Aeryn's hand (and presumably the rest of her) is pleasantly warm to the touch.

> **He reached out to grasp the hand Aeryn extended towards him. The hand
> was warm,** the skin dry, the pressure from her fingers strong. But
> Crichton only had a second to register this before he was pulled
> roughly back to his feet.

Comment: <grumble> Inconsistent scripting. But that will have to do in lieu of consistency! Thanks. I read the novel long ago and didn't recall this passage. No longer have the book.